# Azure App Service health check alert not firing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have an app service with provides a health check endpoint. I have enabled "Health check" on this service and provided the health check endpoint path. I have validated the endpoint in a browser and it is reachable. When everything is running it is reporting a value for the metric of 100. I have set up an alert rule on this metric in Application Insights and tried Average and Min in this rule (< 100). When I kill or stop the service the rule never fires.

It is stated here that this should be possible but I have not found a way to do this:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/24/healthcheck-on-app-service.html#alerts

Also I'm not sure what the 100 even is: %?

In the chart when I hover over the last few minutes it doesn't show a numeric value but rather "--". Which is probably why the rule doesn't fire. Anyone got this working? Is it a bug?

Comment: Another potential solution is to use Application Insights Availability Web Test feature...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to report back, this seems to be working as expected now. It also depends on the type of "unhealthiness" of the service. If you stop the service manually it doesn't fire as it is then a planned stop. If you kill the main process then the service is automatically restarted (as it is seemingly implemented with docker and the main process is the entrypoint). If however you do something for the server to report downness (5XX status code for example on the health endpoint) then it works as expected. The metrics are recorded correctly and thus metric graphs are correct. Alerting on such metrics also works then.

Comment: The logic is that App Service health checks are part of App Service, so if you stop it on purpose, there are no health checks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but as a workaround, we suggest you can take a look at [Application Insights Availability test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability).

It's easy to configure and use for health check purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we need to stick with health checks as we are planning to do more with them (auto-healing, load balancing with healthy nodes etc.)

Comment: @dashambles Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Not really. When a service is stopped per azure / api the metric and rules do not fire. Killing an app causes it to be restarted automatically. Apps that become unhealthy / report 503 on the health endpoint do fire but are seen to flap a lot. I have a support ticket open for this but no fix yet.